# Change uid gid when doing mount command

Tags: mount, nfs

In `/etc/exports`, I configured like that
`/var/vols/tzhong *(rw,sync,anonuid=1999,anongid=1999,root_squash)`
If I mount the nfs folder `/var/vols/tzhong` to my local folder `/mnt/tzhong`. I use root user to create a file under `/mnt/tzhong`, the file ownership will be `1999:1999`. Is that possible to change the uid and gid when doing the mount command? Something like below.

```
mount -t nfs4 -o uid=2000 -o gid=2000 192.168.1.123:/var/vols/tzhong /mnt/tzhong
```

So the ownership of folder `/mnt/tzhong` will be `2000:2000`. Also, all the files created under `/mnt/tzhong` will be `2000:2000`.
But, actually, the command is failed with `mount.nfs4: an incorrect mount option was specified`.

Comment: Assuming you're not using any special user authentication e.g. Kerberos or LDAP, you can try playing with [NFSv4 ID mapping](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/libnfsidmap2/idmapd.conf.5.en.html) on the client side.